# Jinja2: script inside a script tag

Tags: javascript, macros, jinja2

I'm new in the world of JS and Jinja2, so please consider that.

I've a form in which there's another Popup form embedded. Code for Popup Form looks as follows:

```
{% block script %}
    <script type="type/html" data-tpl="popup_form">
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>
            <input class="Btn" type="button" value="Update"/>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script>
        // Calling another script SCRIPT_2
    </script>
{% endblock script %}
```

In that form, I want to add a Time Range Selector for which there's already a JS function defined in another file. To do this, I've added a Jinja2 Macro just above the 'Update' button. Macro function looks like this:

```
{% block script %}
    <script type="type/html" data-tpl="popup_form">
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
        {{ time_range(form) }}      // Macro Calling From Here
        <div>
            <input class="Btn" type="button" value="Update"/>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script>
        // Calling another script SCRIPT_2
    </script>
{% endblock script %}


{% macro time_range(form) %}
    <div>...</div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#id_start_alert_from, #id_end_alert_at')
                .each(modules.timeSelector);
        });
    </script>
{% endmacro %}
```

Now this has added the Time Range Row in the form as I wanted it to but the 'Update' button has gone out of the Popup. I know that the problem is because Jinja2 thinks that the Script has ended because of `</script>` tag is coming from Macro but I don't know how to fix this issue.

I've tried different things in order to call the JS timeSelector function but nothing is working and I need some help from here on..

Comment: `<script type="type/html"` isn't valid, surely?

Comment: I'm also wondering why you have div tags wrapped inside a script tag? Be amazed that those divs render at all.